# R plot tickmarks

Tags: r, plot, axis-labels

I have a plot in R with both `x` and `y-axes` tick labels looking like this:

```
-1.5 -1.0 -0.5 0.0 0.5 1.0
```

1. How can I remove the -`1.5, -0.5, 0.5 tickmarks/labels`?
2. How can I remove the decimal from the remaining labels? (i.e. -`1.0` to become `-1`).

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please read up on how to provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and edit your post accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

So, a plot like this is what I hear you describing:

```
plot(seq(-1.5, 1.1, 0.5),seq(-1.5, 1, 0.5))
```

Adding the xaxp and yaxp vectors will let you fine-tune the labeling:

```
plot(seq(-1.5, 1.1, 0.5),seq(-1.5, 1, 0.5), xaxp=c(-1,1,2), yaxp=c(-1,1,2))
```

The input to xaxp is "A vector of the form c(x1, x2, n) giving the coordinates of the extreme tick marks and the number of intervals between tick-marks when par("xlog") is false." See the help page for par{graphics} for more details

[image: A plot with integer axis labels]

Comment: Perfect!Thanks very much!